# Why am I getting "Erfi" for the Integral of E^x^2?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Grandson & I have been working our way through the calculus of exponential functions.

When we try to integrate `E` to the `x^2`, we get the inaginary error function, "Erfi":

```
Integrate[E^x^2, x]
```

> ```
> 1/2 Sqrt[π] Erfi[x]
> ```

We've read the documentation as well as answers about `Erfi` and just can't seem to understand why we get this result.

Working through the math, we get the result as: (1/2) * (E^x^2).

Comment: You must have made a mistake in working through the math. The Mathematica answer is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issued raised is not really a problem; it is arises from the OP's misunderstanding of the result returned by Mathematica.

Comment: m_Goldberg: Please see my comment below regarding Henrik's answer.  If closing this question it is the right thing to do, how do we do that?

Comment: I still think the question should be closed because any future visitor that reads this thread will not learn anything about Mathematica, which is the purpose of this site. If the question had been asked on Math.SE, it would perhaps have general value, but not here. However, there is only my vote so far and if community thinks I'm wrong, the further four votes needed to close will not be cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily check that the devitative of your "result" does not match `E^x^2`:

```
D[1/2 E^x^2, x]
```

> E^x^2 x

The reason why this outcome differs from yours is the chain rule.

But why is the true result related to `Erfi`. The imaginary error function `Erfi` is related to the error function `Erf` by `Erfi[x]== Erf[I x]/I`. *By definition*, the error function is the stem function of the Gaussian bell function:

```
Integrate[2 Sqrt[1/Pi] E^(-x^2), x]
```

> Erf[x]

The reason why this functions has its own name is that it is not elementary anymore; it cannot be expressed by the usual elementary functions. (By the way, this is not atypical for integrals of elementary functions.)

Because the square of the imaginary unit `I` is `-1`, we may write

```
E^(x^2) == E^(-(I x)^2)
```

> True

Now, the substitution rule shows that `Integrate[E^x^2, x]` should indeed be equal to `1/2 Sqrt[π] Erfi[x]`.

Comment: Henrick: After reading your comments, we went back and looked at the original problem statement and, indeed, you were right: we needed to find the integral of "x * E^x^2".  It all works as it should now.  Thanks for explaining about the Erfi function and we apologize for wasting anyone's time in answering this question.

Comment: @OilerMan No problem, you're welcome.